# Regexp remove txt after specific character in lines (notepad ++)

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++, lines

i have 500 line

```
xyz.blogspot.ae/search/label/Tips >Tips</a>
<span dir= ltr >(3)</span>

xyz.blogspot.ae/search/label/Transformer >Transformer</a>
<span dir= ltr >(10)</span>

xyz.blogspot.ae/search/label/transformer banking >transformer banking</a>
<span dir= ltr >(3)</span>

xyz.blogspot.ae/search/label/Transistor >Transistor</a>
<span dir= ltr >(3)</span>
```

I want to remove everything after  > so it should look like this

```
xyz.blogspot.ae/search/label/Tips

xyz.blogspot.ae/search/label/Transformer

xyz.blogspot.ae/search/label/transformer banking 

xyz.blogspot.ae/search/label/Transistor
```

any regexp ?

Comment: Try replacing `(?:\>).*` with an empty string

Comment: no its remove all remaining lines also after >

Comment: What do you mean by "all remaining lines" ?

Comment: the output is not what i want ... in you regexp only first line is coming as out put

Comment: Please put your attempt in the question.

Comment: @MuhammadAatif which means that you didn't post the proper input! I believe that Avinash's answer is correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `(?s)` modifier to make dot to match even new line characters also.

```
(?s)>.*?(?=\n\n|$)
```

Replacement string:

```
Empty string
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lJ4lF9/8)

Comment: i need for notepad ++ not for php

Comment: is there a newline exists between `</a>` and span tag?

Comment: @MuhammadAatif now try the updated regex. Notepad++ is compatible with PCRE. And don't forget to use the modifier `m`

Comment: xyz.blogspot.ae/search/label/Broadband'>Broadband</a>
<span dir='ltr'>(7)</span>                                             the orignal is like this so i want to remove evrything after '>

Comment: you mean both are in a single line?

Comment: try this `(?s)>.*?(?=\n\n|$)` . Replace the match with empty string.

Comment: Need your help again please check my question ...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30892091/clean-urls-with-regular-expression

Answer (score 2):

```
 ^([^<>]*?)>.*$|.*
```

Try this .this gives the required input.

http://regex101.com/r/iX5xR2/6

Use gm flags

Replace by $1

Comment: Thanks! I used the logic `(\s\d\.\d\d\sGB\s\(\d\))` to remove any characters following the 1st space with the regex pattern group `\1st space \any number \dot \ any number \any number \space GB \space \opening parentesis \any number \closing parenthesis`. Tha removed all the instances of possible combinations of numbers e.g. `4.48 GB (2)` of each line!

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
<span.*|[ ]*>.*
```

With empty string

Answer (score 0):

This might work :

`(<span | >).*` try this in notepad++. You need to replace the above regex with empty Sting (nothing to be entered in the `replace` tab)