# Clean Urls with regular expression

Tags: regex, url, notepad++

i have Data in thousand lines like

> http://xxxx.com/xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx/    60% 2   Weekly  2014-01-01 00:00

want to remove everything after / in every url

(output should be in clean url like below)

> http://xxxx.com/xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx/

Thanks

Comment: i am not good in regular expression .. so any solution with notepad ++ will be appreciated

Comment: @gawi if you cannot answer question don't give negative vote ... its not about your c++ ****

Comment: why do you think it was me? now I'm really tempted to downvote it, you haven't provide any information that is important to help you

Comment: its is just a txt file full with urls and just want to remove all txt in each line after /....  simple

Comment: but which tool do you use to process the text? anyway I gave you answer how to do that in linux cmd as you haven't said anything about OS

Comment: What you need to understand @MuhammadAatif is that your request "a regex for Notepad ++" makes no sense. Notepad ++ is nothing more than a text editor. What you need to specify is the language that will treat your regular expression, so that people can give you specific answers. And you should show us what you tried so far, cause SO is not a "do your homework for you" type of site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the replace menu by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, and make sure regular expressions are enabled.  Then,

**Find** `(^.*\/).*` and **Replace** `$1`:
https://regex101.com/r/lJ4lF9/12

Alternatively, **Find** `(?m)(^.*\/).*` and **Replace** `$1`: https://regex101.com/r/lJ4lF9/13

Explanation:

Within a [capture group](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html), **Find** the start of the string (`^`) followed by anything any number of times (`.*`) until the last "/", then anything any number of times.  **Replace** with the captured group by referencing it as `$1`.

`(?m)`

Comment: i need reg expression for notepad ++

Comment: @MuhammadAatif The reg ex will work in notepad++; just use Find and Replace. I was demonstrating in R because I didn't know you were using notepad++.  See my edit.

Comment: i want to clean everything in each line after last  "  /  "    that's a simple logic question .

Comment: @MuhammadAatif if you don't understand the "logic" of my answer, just ask for clarification.  Additionally, I would advise you to have a look at [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is use linux command line:

```
cat file.txt |cut -f1 -d" "
```

If you are interested in regex then this will match the url in a single line:

```
[^\ ]+
```